# Laravel using Controller@show return view and api

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a web application that will also be turned into a native app so I want to show json from one path and return a view for another path. Here is what I was thinking but not sure how to write the `if` statements in Laravel:

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/notes', 'NotesController@index');
    Route::get('/notes/{note}', 'NotesController@show');
    Route::get('api/notes/{note}', 'NotesController@show');
});
```

NotesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NotesController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {

        $notes = Note::all();

        return view('notes.index', compact('notes'));
    }

    public function show(Note $note) {

        //if its from the general path show view
        return view('notes.show', compact('note'));

        //if its from the api path show json
        return $note;

    }

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it will be better if you used two separate methods. That way they will be easier to debug / modify etc..

Comment: As @AngadDubey says Your API and Web App should really go into separate controllers. Trying to jam everything into the one controller/method will come back to bite you.

Comment: Got ya, just wasnt sure what is best practice.